# why my function not working correctly on addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I just try to show some text on button after user clicking on that button, for example when clicking on btn 'Submit' it changes to 'plz check your...'

My CSS style:

```css
#my-btn:active
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
const myTurn = document.querySelector('#my-btn');
myTurn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myTurn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  myTurn.innerText = 'plz check your...';
});
```

It does not work with above code but work with calling the whole document.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myTurn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  myTurn.innerText = 'plz check your...';
});
```

But the problem with above code is if I click anywhere on the page it would change the button inner text.

Comment: Check the browser console. There may be some errors, otherwise your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. This is your code exactly as you wrote it. I've added a button element with `id="my-btn"` so it can be selected

```js
const myTurn = document.querySelector('#my-btn');
myTurn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myTurn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  myTurn.innerText = 'plz check your...';
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="my-btn">My Button</button>
```